# How to prevent xrdp desktop lock?

Tags: debian, pyautogui, xrdp

I'm using a xrdp remote desktop running Debian and I am running pyautogui on there. When I leave rdp the desktop screen is locked after a few minutes, so pyautogui can't see the desktop anymore. How do I prevent the xrdp desktop from locking?

Comment: This might have fixed it: https://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?p=405365

Comment: Actually it doesn't. The screen still freezes after a while.

Answer (score 0):

This, depending on your DE, the answer differs.

I had this issue with cinnamon, using linux mint. You can tell xrdp to execute custom scripts to unlock the lockscreen. For example in linux mint the command
`cinnamon-screensaver-command --exit`
will exit the screensvaver, avoiding the need to type the password again. Hope this helps someone.

---

Edit:

Considering where xrdp runs, maybe it is best if it is executed as this.

```
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/$UID/bus cinnamon-screensaver-command --exit
```

this would execute for all users. DISPLAY and UID are already set when executing reconnectwm.sh